# Accessing an instance of a class defined in main in another class

Tags: c++, pointers

The problem i've been facing is related to accessing an instance of a class, I'll explain it through a series of code snipets:

If I have a `class Foo` defined as defined below:

```
class Foo {
public:
Foo(){x=5}
private:
   int x;
}
```

And I create an instance of that object in main as follows:

```
int main(){
   Foo a;
}
```

I then want to access that instance of that object in another class and store it:

```
class Bar{
public:
   Bar() {copy = a}
private:
   Foo copy;
}
```

How would that be possible? Is there a way around this? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most natural way would be to pass the `Foo` object as an argument to the `Bar` constructor:

```
Bar(Foo a)
{
    std::cout << a.x << '\n';
}
```

---

For the updated question, I might pass the object as a constant reference instead of by value:

```
Bar(Foo const& a)
    : copy{ a }
{
}
```

This will initialize the member variable `copy` to be a copy of the `Foo` object that `a` references.

---

For the Qt special case, you should almost never make copies of `QObject`-derived objects. Instead you should have *pointers* to them:

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(Foo* a)
        : pointer{ a }
    {
    }

private:
    Foo* pointer;
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I just made a change in the question and made it a bit clearer but I would need to store it or point at it in some sort of way. I'm using Qt and QObject can not be copied in any case.

Comment: @unity123 Doesn't really change my answer. You still need to pass the object to the `Bar` constructor. Possibly by a (`const`) reference.

Comment: The problem with that is I get the following error: "parser.cpp:5:22: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'Device'
device.h:10:16: note: copy constructor of 'Device' is implicitly deleted because base class 'QObject' has a deleted copy constructor
qobject.h:467:20: note: 'QObject' has been explicitly marked deleted here". I thought about your solution but it wouldn't let me.

Comment: @unity123 Qt object should almost never be copied, you only use pointers.